# SQL Server, updating item quantities of new items that are replacing old items

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a CSV with two columns OldItem and NewItem; each column holds a list of integers. Note - the CSV will hold around 1,000 rows.

```
OldItem | NewItem
-----------------
1021669 | 1167467
1021680 | 1167468
1021712 | 1167466
1049043 | 1000062
```

We have old items in the system that are being replaced by the new items and we would like to capture the current quantity of the first OldItem and assign it to the first NewItem, quantity of second OldItem assigned to quantity of third OldItem, etc.

The other fun part of the issue is that the Item Numbers that are in the spreadsheet don't match up to the item numbers associated with the quantities, there's a translation table in the system called Alias.

Here are the tables and columns we're interacting with:
table Alias (essentially a translation table)
column Alias (the numbers in the spreadsheet)
column ItemID (the numbers in table "Items" that hold the quantities)

table Items (this holds all the items, new and old)
column ItemID
column Quantity

The only way I can think of doing this is doing a foreach on every OldItem like this, pseudo-code incoming:
foreach OldItem (Select Alias.ItemID WHERE Alias.Alias = OldItem) 
then somehow, as I don't know how to return and use that result in SQL:
Select Item.Quantity where Item.ItemID = Alias.ItemID. 
At this point I have the quantity that I want, now I have to reference back to the CSV, find the NewItem associated with the OldItem, and do this all over again with the NewItem and then update the NewItem Quantity to the one I found from the OldItem.

-dizzy-

Please help, I could solve this problem by wrapping SQL in PowerShell to handle the logical bits but it has severe performance consequences and I have to do this on MANY databases remotely with very bad network connections!

Comment: I suggest importing the CSV into a work table (using BCP or SSIS or even SSMS can do it now) then using T-SQL to do your work. T-SQL is much faster at set operations especially for larger sets. But I have a T-SQL background so I'm biased

Comment: Is it a one-time task or you will need to repeat it every time a new set of items is replaced?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I don't actually know what the differences are between the different SQL languages, however I'm restricted to whatever can run by default against a MS SQL Database, this all relates to MS RMS DBs. Unfortunately I think your comment assumes a much higher level of knowledge of SQL than I have, as this is my first time writing SQL at all.

Comment: @FDavidov This is theoretically a one time task per DB, it has to be done at many stores on their individual DBs but it would be a one time task per store regardless. This kind of thing won't be done again for years and we won't even have RMS by then.

Comment: T-SQL is just SQL Servers SQL language. It's probably quite straightforward to write you some scripts to do it but you should be comfortable with the process. It will certainly solve the bad network connectivity issue because there is very little network traffic - all processing happen in the database at the site. Do the new item records _already_ exist in the item table or do they need to be created?

Comment: Anyway this is what I would propose: 1. Add a calculated column to your CSV that generates the insert statement for the item, 2; Run the script (rerunnable so if the connection breaks you can run it again without duplicates). to insert records into a working table; 3. Run a script that confirms all of the new items have already been created. 3. Run an update script that copies the stock levels over. Can you clarify what access level you have? Are you able to create tables?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've been messing with this for over a week, I'm generally comfortable with messing around with the DB in MS SQL Management Studio, running SQL I've found, etc. I normally solve this kind of issue with PowerShell, unfortunately that's not an option this time :(

I can get you any information needed if you wish to help further, I could even do this pretty easily if the old items and new items were on different Tables but that's not the case either and someone advised me against creating temp tables which has made this extremely difficult.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have unrestricted access, I could theoretically do anything. I think perhaps trying to do this without creating a temp table has been making my job way more difficult than needed. I think I should go try some new things based on what you've said and return with my results.

Comment: I'm cooking up an answer but... can you confirm that that `Items` only holds the current quantity - it's not a list of quantities over time? Also can you confirm that OldItems is a unique list, and newitems are only ever mapped to once?

Comment: Well, if this is going to be a one time task / store, I would recommend you do all the manipulations in Excel (quite easy; you can achieve what you need using simple worksheet functions) and then have the CSV with the new data ready. Note that the same Excel with the _manipulations mechanisms_ can be reused for each and every store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have connectivity issues, I suggest the following:

1. Create a working table in your database
2. Import your CSV into the working table
3. Run a script that copies aliases and quantities into the working table. Not required but helps with auditing
4. Run a script that validates the data
5. Run a script that copies required data into `Items`

It's important to note that this assumes that olditems are unique, and only ever map to one new item. There is a checks in the 'testing section' for that

## Create a working table

Open SQL Server Management Studio and run this script in your database (choose it in the dropdown)

```
 -- Create a schema to hold working tables that aren't required by the application
 CREATE SCHEMA adm;

-- Now create a table in this schema
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'ItemTransfer' 
           AND type = 'U' 
           AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('adm'))
    DROP TABLE adm.ItemTransfer;

CREATE TABLE adm.ItemTransfer (
    OldItem INT NOT NULL, 
    NewItem INT NOT NULL,
    OldAlias VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    NewAlias VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    OldQuantity NUMERIC(19,2) NULL
   );
```

## Import the CSV data

There are a number of ways to do this. Your constraint is your unreliable network, and how comfortable you are troubleshooting unfamiliar tools. Here is one method that can be rerun without causing duplicates:

Open your CSV in excel and paste this monstrosity into in column 3, row 2:

```
="INSERT INTO adm.ItemTransfer (OldItem, NewItem) SELECT " & A2 & "," & B2 & " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM adm.ItemTransfer WHERE OldItem=" & A2 & " AND NewItem=" & B2 & ");"
```

This will generate an insert statement for that data. Drag it down to generate all insert statements. There will be a bunch of lines that look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO adm.ItemTransfer (OldItem, NewItem) SELECT 1,2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM adm.ItemTransfer WHERE OldItem=1 AND NewItem=2);
```

Copy/paste this string of inserts into SQL Server Management Studio and run it. It should insert all of the data into your working table.

I also suggest that you save this file to a .SQL file. This insert statement only inserts if the record isn't already there, so it can be rerun.

**Note:** There are many ways to import data into SQL Server. the next easiest way is to right click on the database / tasks / import flat file, but it's more complicated to stop duplicates / restarting import

Now you can run `SELECT * FROM adm.ItemTransfer` and you should see all of your records

## Map Alias and Qty

This step can actually be done on the fly but lets just write them into the working table as it will allow us to audit afterwards

These two scripts copy the alias into the working table:

```
UPDATE adm.ItemTransfer
SET OldAlias = SRC.Alias
FROM 
adm.ItemTransfer TGT
INNER JOIN
Alias SRC
ON TGT.OldItem = SRC.ItemID;


UPDATE adm.ItemTransfer
SET NewAlias = SRC.Alias
FROM 
adm.ItemTransfer TGT
INNER JOIN
Alias SRC
ON TGT.NewItem = SRC.ItemID;
```

This one copies in the old item quantity

```
UPDATE adm.ItemTransfer
SET OldQuantity = SRC.Quantity
FROM 
adm.ItemTransfer TGT
INNER JOIN
Items SRC
ON TGT.OldAlias = SRC.ItemID;
```

After these steps, again run the select statement to inspect.

## Pre update check

Before you actually do the update you should check data consistency

Count of records in the staging table:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS TableCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT OldAlias) UniqueOldAlias,
COUNT(DISTINCT NewAlias) UniqueNewAlias,
FROM adm.ItemTransfer
```

The numbers should all be the same and should match the CSV record count. If not you have a problem as you are missing records or you are not mapping one to one

This select shows you old items missing an alias:

```
SELECT * FROM adm.ItemTransfer WHERE OldAlias IS NULL
```

This select shows you new items missing an alias:

```
SELECT * FROM adm.ItemTransfer WHERE NewAlias IS NULL
```

This select shows you old items missing from the item table

```
SELECT * 
FROM adm.ItemTransfer T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM Items I WHERE I.ItemID = T.OldItem)
```

This select shows you new items missing from the item table

```
SELECT * 
FROM adm.ItemTransfer T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM Items I WHERE I.ItemID = T.NewItem)
```

## Backup the table and do the update

First backup the table *inside* the database like this:

```
SELECT *
INTO adm.Items_<dateandtime>
FROM Items
```

This script makes a copy of the Items table before you update it. You can delete it later if you like

The actual update is pretty simple because we worked it all out in the working table beforehand:

UPDATE Items
SET Quantity = SRC.OldQuantity
FROM Items TGT
INNER JOIN 
adm.ItemTransfer SRC
ON SRC.NewAlias = TGT.ItemID;

## Summary

All of this can be bundled up into a script and automated if required. As is, you should save all working files to a SQL file, as well as the outputs from the SELECT test statements